# Are dynamically allocated objects default initialized?

Tags: c++, initialization, language-lawyer

In C++ Primer 5th (chapter 12),

> By default, dynamically allocated objects are default initialized, which means that objects of built-in or compound type have undefined value;

```
int *pi = new int; // unitialized int
```

This statement indicates that built-in type object has undefined value when default initialized. However, **the behaviour of default initialized built-in type object depends on where it is defined**.

To be specific, built-in type object outside any function shall be `0`, while built-in type object inside some block has undefined value.

Hence, I think the statement above is not accurate，since for built-in type:

**default initialized != undefined value**

Do I understand this properly?

Comment: global vars and local vars are not in the same memory on whatever device is executing the code. Local dynamic allocated variables are located on the heap and global variables have a separated heap, so maybe that's why they seem to be initialized with zero and locals are not. But that's just guessing with some little knowledge..

Answer (score 8):

For non-class types, default initialization performs no initialization.

However, variables with static or thread storage duration are always zero-initialized before any other initialization takes place. So if you have `int x;` at the global scope, although the default initialization does nothing, `x` is still initialized to zero due to the zero-initialization that takes place before the default initialization.

For a non-class object with dynamic storage duration, if no initializer is given, the value is indeterminate because zero-initialization does not apply.